# How to add static route in Linux (comparing to Windows)

Tags: linux, networking, routing

On Windows, I just type:

```
C:\Users\WindowsUser>route add 8.8.8.8 mask 255.255.255.255 10.25.10.28
OK!
```

(my ip 10.10.201.15/8)

With Linux (its ip 10.10.201.16/8) on *eht0*

```
route add -net 8.8.8.8 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 10.25.10.28 dev eth0
```

and ip route shows: 8.8.8.8 via 10.25.10.28 dev eth0

but it goes out the default gateway when I do a traceroute on 8.8.8.8 (def gw is 10.0.0.1). Any tips?

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  0.277 ms  0.246 ms  0.513 ms'
```

ip r shows: (my public addresses removed for safety)

```
8.8.8.8 via 10.25.10.28 dev eth0  metric 1
10.0.0.0/8 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.10.130
10.0.0.0/8 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.10.125
default via mypubicip dev eth0.2
```

I read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/521586/linux-route-command-two-gatways-on-the-same-subnet-range#autocomment1350609) but did not help.

Comment: yep dried that to, metric 1 same results.

Comment: 8.8.8.8 via 10.25.10.28 dev eth0  metric 1

Comment: added ip r command to qestion

Comment: thank you. . . ..

Comment: Two questions: Are 10.25.10.28 and 10.0.0.1 on the same host? You said nothing about 10.0.0.1 and it does not show in your `ip r`, yet the kernel thinks that's the next hop. What is 10.0.0.1?

Comment: in the question i said (def gw is 10.0.0.1) .  yes its on teh same host

Comment: Then your routes are ok. In multihomed hosts there is no guarantee about which IP `traceroute` will report.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that 10.25.10.28 and 10.0.0.1 are on the "same host", then maybe the traceroute is using the correct route on the Linux system.  Maybe it's the gateway (10.25.10.28 and 10.0.0.1) that is using a different route (or simply a different source IP) to get back to the Linux system.  Although many systems that respond to a traceroute packet will respond using their IP from the interface they received the traceroute packet on, they don't have to.

Note: For "same host", I'll assume that we are using the term host to mean an OS instance and not to mean a hypervisor (host vs guest).

You mention that the "def gw is 10.0.0.1", yet the output from "ip r" shows "default via mypubicip dev eth0.2", so I'm tempted to say that your default gateway is not 10.0.0.1.  I would ask for clarification via a comment but I cannot add comments yet.  For now, I'll assume 10.0.0.1 is the "usual" default route in your environment but it does not apply to your Linux system.

Comment: def gateway on eth0 is 10.0.0.1 .

Comment: there is a eth0.2 that gives me a public address that is dhcp  but that is completely different and a WAN ip address per ARIN routing

Comment: I see nothing about 10.0.0.1 in the output of your "ip r" command.  Did you post the whole output?

Comment: On the Linux system, what does "ip route get 8.8.8.8" output?